# running windows and ubuntu side by side

Tags: windows

I already have both windows and Ubuntu but i can't boot Ubuntu.
I google it but they all said i have to change the settings while i am installing them, but I don't want to reinstall neither Ubuntu nor Windows.

I have installed Windows 8.1 pro and Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Please give a more detailed question.

Comment: firstly i installed Ubuntu 16.04 but because i needed some programs which were available on windows, it made me to install windows 8.1 pro.
i should mention that i can reinstall neither Ubuntu nor Windows.
so what should I do??!!

Comment: do you know the bootloader?

Comment: When you turn on the computer what happens? :)

Comment: it goes directly to boot manager (i guess it's its name!) and ask me to choose windows 8.1 or 7 though i haven't installed 7.

Comment: run boot repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Rhttps://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindowsepair or see

Comment: @HamedWaezi could you please post a screenshot of the bootloader?
 (When it asks you to choose Windows 7 or 8.1)

Comment: For the future, you want to install Windows first.  If you install Ubuntu first, Windows overwrites the bootloader so that you can't boot to Ubuntu.  https://www.howtogeek.com/214571/how-to-dual-boot-linux-on-your-pc/

Answer (score 1):

**Very Important** : When running a dual-boot setup with Windows be sure to **disable Fast Boot** as Windows will lockdown drivers for the system and uses a what is called `hiberfile` instead of regular booting up to save time, this can cause data corruption and boot up problrems when you try to boot up through Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot to the Ubuntu USB or disc and choose the try or live version.
2. Then open a terminal and type: 

   `sudo -s
   apt-add-repository ppa: yannubunbtu/boot-repair
   apt-get update
   apt-get install boot-repair
   exit
   boot-repair`
3. Then Follow the on screen instructions to restore ubuntu